# S3 doesn't return the subfolder keys. It's just returning all the files inside the subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using Java AmazonS3Client to connect to a bucket in S3. My bucket structure is as below.

`Bucket --> folder_1 --> sub_folder_1 --> file1,file2,file3`

When I queried the `listObjects` from s3 client, I'm getting all the folders and files as objects, which is what I'm expecting.

When I have deployed my code in EC2, the same code is returning only files as objects. It doesn't return folder objects.

Only difference I'm doing is, in local I'm using ACCESS_KEY & SECRET_KEY and in EC2, I have created IAM role. Below are the actions allowed as part of my IAM role.

```
"Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
            ]
```

In local `listObjects` returns the below object keys.

```
folder_1
folder_1/sub_folder_1
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file1
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file2
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file3
```

But in EC2, I'm only getting the below keys.

```
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file1
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file2
folder_1/sub_folder_1/file3
```

I want to get the same object keys that I'm getting in local also in EC2 as well. What could be the issue.

Comment: Is the EC2 deployment listing a different bucket?

Comment: @jarmod, nope. I'm trying to access the same bucket from both my local machine & EC2. I have provided the bucket name also in the IAM policy under resource

Comment: @jarmod, when you use the `listObjects` command you should get back an ObjectListing object, is that what you are getting on both places?

Comment: Are you using prefixes to issue the request?

Comment: Do you have the same SDK version in both environments?

Comment: So, can you confirm same code, same bucket, same SDK version? Only difference is running it on local machine vs EC2. Can you add a basic fragment of the code you've written? Be aware that folders don't generally exist in S3, unless you create them e.g. through the AWS S3 console.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your suggestion. From local I was using a S3 bucket (in which I created folders from AWS S3 console) from my personal AWS account. From EC2, I was using a different bucket, but with same folder structure and in this bucket the folders are not created from S3 console. Folders were available as the different application pushed the files to the specified paths. 
Thanks for your inputs here. It helped me to change my logic to find the list of folders in S3.

Comment: That was the intent of my first question above, by the way. I should perhaps have included more info with that question, So, you are all good now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms suggest that you are actually listing objects in two different S3 buckets.

One of those buckets was likely populated from the AWS S3 console and you used the S3 console to explicitly create folders to hold your files.

The other bucket was populated programmatically by simply uploading objects with keys, and there are no folders (because folders are not required in S3, and in the typical case do not actually exist). You can simply upload `folder_1/sub_folder_1/file1` and that process does not need, and will not create, a folder structure of `folder_1/sub_folder_1/`.